# mongoose : Discriminator with name " " already exists

Tags: mongoose, nodes

I'm using mongoose to interact with mongoDB in a rest API,
and while using discriminators, I get this error :

Discriminator with name "serviceMember" already exists

know that with this code everything is fine :

```js
const serviceManagerSchema = new Schema({
    serviceId : {
     type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref : 'service'
    },
    serviceMembers : [{
     type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref : 'serviceMember'
    }] 
},options)

const ServiceManager = Employee.discriminator('serviceManager',serviceManagerSchema)
```

but this doesn't work

```js
const serviceMemberSchema = new Schema({
 
 },options)

const ServiceMember = Employee.discriminator('serviceMember',serviceMemberSchema)

module.exports = ServiceMember
```

I have tried to replace the "serviceMember" name with another name that i'm sure i have never used it, but still the same error

Help me please, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has cobwebs on it, but in case anyone else ever comes here looking for a solution to this problem here's how I solved it. In my case I was getting this error due to using Mongoose with Next.js - everytime Next hot reloaded my model module (in my case, the base model is called 'User'), all of the discriminators would collide.

To solve the issue, I had to delete the discriminator model (because Mongoose creates a full-fledged model for each discriminator) and then also delete the discriminator from the User model:

```js
// Patient handler
if (mongoose.modelNames().includes('patient')) {
  log.trace('Deleting patient model');
  mongoose.deleteModel('patient');
}

if (User.discriminators && 'patient' in User.discriminators) {
  log.trace('Deleting patient discriminator');
  delete User.discriminators.patient;
}

const Patient = User.discriminator(
  'patient',
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      healthCard: { type: String, unique: true },
      homePhone: { type: String },
      birthDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    },
    options
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In development environments that use hot-reload or similar, an instance of the `model`/`discriminator` can already be cached. Since `mongoose` does not allow models with the same name, you get this error. You can first check the `mongoose.models` variable first to see if there is an instance of the base class in memory. Then, if it does not exist, you can create an instance:

```
const Base = mongoose.models.Base || mongoose.model('Base', Schema);
```

The same principle applies to the discriminator:

```
const Inherited = 
    mongoose.models.Base.discriminators.Inherited || 
    Base.discriminator('Inherited', InheritedSchema)
```

The key here is to use the `||` operator to only create a model when one with the same name does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ServiceManager = Employee.discriminators != undefined ?  Employee.discriminators['serviceManager'] : Employee.discriminator('serviceManager',serviceManagerSchema)
```